# Swift PickerView label error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var picker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

```
var Array = ["Iphone", "겔럭시", "베가아이언"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return Array[row]
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return Array.count
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
                    label.text = Array[row]       ///this part error "use of unresolved identifier row"


}
```

}

could you explain to me the difference between the error row and row that  I used for title above?

why I would get error for the bottom one. I declare correctly I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am assuming you want the label's text to change when the user taps a button)

This function runs when the pickerView's value has changed(the `row` parameter that you were trying to use, runs when the pickerView is being made, not when the value has changed)-

```
 func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
```

Also, you want to create a global variable so you can use `row`(the `row` parameter in the didSelectRow function can only be used inside that function) in your `IBAction` function.

So add this piece of code under the class definition-

```
var rowSelected = 0
```

Next, add this function to your code -

```
 func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
      rowSelected = row
}
```

And finally, change the `label.text = Array[row]` to `label.text = Array[rowSelected]`(this should also make your unresolved identifier error dissappear) .

So your whole code should look like this-

```
var rowSelected = 0
var Array = ["Iphone", "겔럭시", "베가아이언"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return Array[row]
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return Array.count
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
       label.text = Array[rowSelected]


}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
      rowSelected = row
}
```

Hopefully that worked out.

Comment: Thank you for very detail explanation.